# How to validate dynamic string condition with request string condition in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am using laravel framework to develop API's,now one scenario facing i have one column inside database which will store as a string (Actually i am using that string to check in where condition in queries).Now want to check weather new request is valid request or duplicate request.For some scenarios it was working but it's failing for some scenario. i will give some examples which scenario it was working or which scenario it was not working

**Existing Record data**

"price=10 AND order=1"

**working scenario**

$req = "price=10 AND order=1";

**Not working scenario**

$req = "order=1 AND price=10";

Technically order is different so it's not a valid scenario but it comes to **user perspective** it also a valid condition so i need to validate both incoming condition with existing conditions.is there any way to check both conditions are equal or not ?

Note:- my condition will be separated with AND,OR,!= and conditional string will be dynamic

Comment: How are you checking if duplicate requests are coming? Are you storing current requests made in some table?

Comment: @nice_dev, i am not storing anywhere but i am checking in before save() method if it exists means i will return error instead of calling save()

Comment: @nice_dev, it's a form from the form i am saving request into columns inside database of column name condition.for next form submission i need to validate request with the database column condition

Comment: Well, you can just check if the entry exists in the DB table and throw the error accordingly.

Comment: Since you are doing mere string comparison, you would need to bring the "parts" into the same order in both. With something as simple as `price=10 AND order=1` you could just split this apart at `[space]AND[space]`, then for example sort the resulting parts alphabetically, and then join them in that order with `[space]AND[space]` again. But as soon as your expressions get more complex - using `OR`as well, grouping braces maybe, other logical operators perhaps - it of course won't be that simply any more. Then you'd need an expression parser that _understands_ the logic to start.

Comment: Please share more details. How is this problem related to MySQL? What did you try to resolve it?